# What will happen by calling [super alloc] in a subclass' factory method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Sample code as follow:

Class1.h:

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject
@end
```

Class1.m

```
@implementation Class1
@end
```

Class2.h:

```
@interface Class2 : Class1
+ (instancetype)class2;
@end
```

Class2.m:

```
@implementation Class2
+ (instancetype)class2 {
    return [[super alloc] init];
}
@end
```

main.m:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    Class1* o = [Class2 class2];
    NSLog(@"%@", [o className]);    // shows 'Class2'
    return 0;
}
```

The results shows that calling `[super alloc]` in a subclass' factory method still creates an object of the subclass.  So it's practically the same as calling `[self alloc]` in this case?  What happens exactly behind the scene when calling `[super alloc]`?  How does compiler and runtime handle this?  Is there any specific scenario where calling `[super alloc]` will make a meaningful difference than `[self alloc]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let us see an example

```
+ (instancetype)class2 {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([super class]));
    return [[super alloc] init];
}
```

This will log

> class2

**1. So, what is `super` in Objective-C?**

The difference between `self` and `super` is that using `self`, the Objective-C runtime will start looking for the method implementation from the subclass, but using `super`, it will start looking for the method implementation from the super class.

**2. When to use `[self alloc]` or `[super alloc]`?**

First, you have to know that almost all classes in Objective-C is a subclass of `NSObject`, and `alloc` is class method of `NSObject`.

Second, you do not need to override the `alloc` method in the subclass, so no matter you call `[self alloc]` or `[super alloc]`, the runtime will still using `[NSObject alloc]`.

From the document:

> Do not override alloc to include initialization code. Instead, implement class-specific versions of init... methods.

Comment: It is a bad idea to override `alloc` but I can still override it and return something else, which means `[NSObject alloc]` is not always called. There are many (bad) singleton implementations override `alloc` to guarantee singleness

Answer (score 1):

Calling `[super method]` never returns the `super`'s class.  Think of the common case of

```
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    ...
}
return self;
```

that forms the boilerplate of every init method.  If the call to `[super init]` returned an instance of `super`'s class, it wouldn't work very well :)

The logical conclusion would then be that `[super alloc]` is functionally equivalent to `[self alloc]`, unless the subclass has overridden `alloc`.  As this is never done in practice, they are the same for all practical cases.

I would still not do it, however.  It looks like something tricky is going on, even when there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You're not overriding the `alloc` method, so it doesn't matter whether you call `[self alloc]` or `[super alloc]`.  Both cases will simply execute the base class method `+[NSObject alloc]`.  And in both cases `self` refers to `Class2`.

The implementation of `+[NSObject alloc]` then takes care of allocating an instance of `Class2`.